# Compact sets of Hausdorff dimension zero

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

I have a question about Hausdorff dimension. Suppose S is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose Hausdorff dimension is zero. Does it follow that S can be covered by a finite DISJOINT union of closed disks with arbitrary small (positive) radius?

Comment: Do you want the disks to be disjoint in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of forming a disjoint family when intersected with the set in question? I think the latter you can do simply by total disconnectedness.

Comment: @Teri I actually want the disks to be disjoint in $\mathbb{R}^n$.